# My onlick has 2 functions - but I need one to fire after the other?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I'm no Js expert so im struggling with this somewhat! I hope I can explain this....

This is in a PhoneGap app / iOS and Android.

I have a link the plays an audio file:

```
<span class="play" onclick="loader(); playAudio('http://a797.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music/72/89/b9/mzi.aytblawp.aac.p.m4a','t3')"  id="t3">
```

So clicking does 2 functions `loader()` makes a 'loading' icon appear and "playAudio" plays a track.

Heres the js for the functions:

```
<script>
    function loader() {
        $(".loading").addClass("loadingnow");
    }
</script>

<script>
    function playAudio(src,trackname) {
        //  alert('trackname:' + trackname);
        if (audioPlaying === false) {
            if (device.platform == 'Android') {
                src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
            }
            media = new Media(src, success, error_error);
            media.play();
            //add playing class
            document.getElementById(trackname).parentNode.className="playing";
            $(".loading").removeClass("loadingnow");
            audioPlaying = true;
        } else {
            //audio is already playing
        }
    }

    function success() {
        $(".playing").removeClass("playing");
        $(".loading").removeClass("loadingnow");
        audioPlaying = false;
    }

    function error_error(e) {
        //alert('great error');
        //alert(e.message);
    }

    function stopAudio() {
        if (media) {
            media.stop();
            audioPlaying = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

There is a slight delay for the audio to load - so that is why I have a loader icon appear but in the app all that happens is the audio plays - the loader does not appear. (In the playAudio function when the audio plays it removes the loader)

How do I make the onlick do the loader function and make sure thats done before doing the playAudio function?!?!!

Really stuck!!

Comment: Seems strange ... What append if you try to execute only the `loader` function and not the `PlayAudio` ? does the icon appear ?

Comment: And if you try in a web browser (not the app) ?

Comment: Yeah, if I remove the playAudio function the loader appears onclick fine - obviously no audio plays.

Comment: Why not use a single function in response to the click? In that function you would first add the `loadingNow` class and _then_ call the `playAudio` function.

Comment: In the browser the loader appears when I click the play button - i guess its not running the playAudio part as its not in an app just a browser

Comment: enhzflep - that would be great! but i have no idea how to write that code - been looking / playing with it all day ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off pull this into a JS file - no one likes inline JS....

Second have a function that fires both of them

**HTML**

```
<span class="play" onclick="loadPlay('http://a797.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music/72/89/b9/mzi.aytblawp.aac.p.m4a','t3')"  id="t3">
```

**JS**

```
<script>
   function loadPlay(src, trackName) {
       loader();
       playAudio(src, trackName);
   }

   function loader() {
        $(".loading").addClass("loadingnow");
    }

    function playAudio(src,trackname) {
        //  alert('trackname:' + trackname);
        if (audioPlaying === false) {
            if (device.platform == 'Android') {
                src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
            }
            media = new Media(src, success, error_error);
            media.play();
            //add playing class
            document.getElementById(trackname).parentNode.className="playing";
            audioPlaying = true;
        } else {
            //audio is already playing
        }
    }

    function success() {
        $(".playing").removeClass("playing");
        $(".loading").removeClass("loadingnow");
        audioPlaying = false;
    }

    function error_error(e) {
        //alert('great error');
        //alert(e.message);
    }

    function stopAudio() {
        if (media) {
            media.stop();
            audioPlaying = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Both your suggestions are good design, but why do you think it will fix the problem?

Comment: Ok - I'll give this a go - give me 2 mins!

Comment: I agree with last Sten Muchow comment. Only one function, separated js file ... and remove the `removeClass` line. :D

Comment: Thanks All, Sods law... the phonegap build sever is down so I cant test right now... but i will as soon as its back up! THANKS

Comment: Also Sten Muchow, after trying your answer I commented each of the functions out to test and they work correctly,  loader(); - loads the loader and playAudio(src, trackName); - plays the audio after the slight pause.

But when they are both called there is the slight pause then the audio plays and loader appears?

When the audio is finished or my stop button is clicked the spinner goes away and audio stops.

Comment: More digging... it seems the success function is for the track has completed playing - NOT loaded and playing?

I need a way pf checking the audio is playing i think? and if it is tell the loader to go away?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line:

```
$(".loading").removeClass("loadingnow");
```

from `playAudio()`. It should only be done in the `success()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is the root cause, but maybe you should remove the commented line below:

```
function playAudio(src,trackname) {
    //  alert('trackname:' + trackname);
    if (audioPlaying === false) {
        if (device.platform == 'Android') {
            src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
            }
            media = new Media(src, success, error_error);
            media.play();
            //add playing class
            document.getElementById(trackname).parentNode.className="playing";
           // $(".loading").removeClass("loadingnow");  <------ this line removes immediately the class. The sucess function will do this, once the media is loaded 
            audioPlaying = true;
            } else {
            //audio is already playing
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Sten Muchow - I moved the js into a .js file as you said and changed the play button also.

Now when I press play there is a slight pause (but no loader as there should be) and then the loader appears at the same time the audio plays?